Note on standard errors reported by `flexsurv` package as compared to `survival` package
My original question (which is below) was about converting standard errors reported by  flexsurv to the standard errors reported by survival, since I thought they are different only because of the different parameterization used. Since then, I have learnt a few things about the way flexsurv calculates the standard errors in some cases and realized that it is not a parameterization issue. I will record this learning as an answer below, just in case someone else also encounters this difference between the 2 packages.
Original question
I understand that the parameterization used in the flexsurv package is different to the parameterization in the survival package. I have fit the same log-normal regression model using both packages. The documentation for flexsurvreg mentions that it is only a wrapper for survreg for distributions like log-normal and it only converts the results into the parameterizations used in flexsurvreg. I want to find out how the conversion is done for the regression co-efficient standard errors. The point estimates in the output match, but the standard errors of the regression co-efficients do not. (Note that the standard error of Scale (in survival package) does match the standard error of sdlog in flexsurvreg. Just the regression co-efficients' standard errors are different) The data is available here, with the independent variable Stress box cox transformed with lambda = -2.
Output from survival:
> para_fit_logNormal.lambda <- survival::survreg(Surv(Cycles, delta) ~ Stress.boxCox, data = laminatePanel, dist = "lognormal")
>   
> summary(para_fit_logNormal.lambda)

Call:
survival::survreg(formula = Surv(Cycles, delta) ~ Stress.boxCox, 
    data = laminatePanel, dist = "lognormal")
                  Value Std. Error     z      p
(Intercept)    8.10e+05   1.76e+04  46.0 <2e-16
Stress.boxCox -1.62e+06   3.52e+04 -46.0 <2e-16
Log(scale)    -7.16e-01   6.69e-02 -10.7 <2e-16

Scale= 0.489 

Log Normal distribution
Loglik(model)= -889.6   Loglik(intercept only)= -1065.1
    Chisq= 350.97 on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 2.6e-78 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 7 
n= 125 

Output from flexsurvreg:
> (para_fit_logNormal.lambda.flexsurv <- flexsurv::flexsurvreg(Surv(Cycles, delta) ~ Stress.boxCox, data = laminatePanel, dist = "lnorm"))
Call:
flexsurv::flexsurvreg(formula = Surv(Cycles, delta) ~ Stress.boxCox, 
    data = laminatePanel, dist = "lnorm")

Estimates: 
               data mean  est        L95%       U95%     
meanlog               NA   8.10e+05   8.10e+05   8.10e+05
sdlog                 NA   4.89e-01   4.29e-01   5.57e-01
Stress.boxCox   5.00e-01  -1.62e+06  -1.62e+06  -1.62e+06
               se         exp(est)   L95%       U95%     
meanlog         2.92e+01         NA         NA         NA
sdlog           3.26e-02         NA         NA         NA
Stress.boxCox   5.85e+01   0.00e+00   0.00e+00   0.00e+00

N = 125,  Events: 115,  Censored: 10
Total time at risk: 684875.4
Log-likelihood = -889.6152, df = 3
AIC = 1785.23



I fit log normal regression models using the 2 packages mentioned above to a different dataset where the regression coefficient point estimates are much smaller (less than 10). The standard errors reported by both packages matched! This makes me question whether this is even a parameterization issue. I wonder whether the scale of the point estimates in the question above (close to 1 million) is somehow causing this discrepancy?

If you see very large or tiny estimates for regression coefficients, you should rescale your data in order to avoid issues from limited precision of floating-point numbers. (I can't look at the data because the hosting service doesn't support my web browser.)

As per the documentation in flexsurv: "For the Weibull (and exponential, log-normal and log-logistic) distribution, flexsurvreg simply acts as a wrapper for survreg: the maximum likelihood estimates are obtained by survreg, checked by flexsurvreg for optimisation convergence, and converted to flexsurvreg’s preferred parameterisation."
In one of the responses to an issue on the flexsurv github page, the author mentions: "For Weibull models, flexsurv actually wraps a survreg fit to get the initial values, then runs its own optimisation just to double check it's converged." I am assuming that the same is done for log-normal models as well.
Now, survival package uses analytical second derivatives to construct the Hessian matrix, whereas flexsurv uses analytical second derivatives only for "Weibull, exponential, Gompertz, and the hazard or odds-based spline models". For the log-normal models, numerical differentiation is used. See the author's response again here. Notice that in the question I posted, the scale of the estimates are very different. The regression co-efficients are close to 1 million and negative 1.5 million, but the scale parameter is around 0.5. This is probably the reason why the numerical method for finding the derivatives does poorly as compared to analytical derivatives. When I fit log-normal model using the 2 packages to a different dataset where all the ML estimates were less than 10, the standard errors match.
Side note: What is the intent behind comparing the standard errors of the 2 packages? The reason why I am doing this is because flexsurv package has the ability to fit models where the location and scale parameters depend on covariates. As far as I know, survival package can fit models where only the  location parameter depends on covariates (If this is incorrect, please do let me know!). I wanted to compare the standard errors in the constant scale case to try and figure out the different parameterizations between the 2, but it led to a compete different learning about how each package constructs the Hessian matrix! I suppose one can still use flexsurv for fitting log-normal models where the scale depends on co-variates, but construct your own Hessian matrix by computing the second derivatives of the log likelihood in order to get the standard errors of the estimates when the scale of the ML estimates are very different.
